# Ionic changes state on using InAppBrowser

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I am trying to open link with InAppBrowser using simple code:

```
$scope.openDocument = function(url) {
                window.open(url, '_blank', 'location=yes');
}
```

It opens, however, state of application is changed into starting page of the app.

Any ideas how to prevent reseting of the state?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after some investigation i found fix which is working for me:

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, to, toParams, from, fromParams) {
        if (to.url == '/preinit'){
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    });
```

preinit - is a state which can be called only on application start, that is why, if i see that event - we just ignoring it.

Not sure that it will work for everyone, but in my case it worked :)